# How to declare a string resource that bound to a property?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xaml, resources

As you may know, we can declare a string "variable" using resource:

```
<sys:String x:Key="someKey">someValue</sys:String>
```

I want to replace **someValue** by a binding property, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible. But even then, why do you need to do this. Couldn't your controls just bind to the same string instead of using the resource?

Comment: I asked since assigning the ribbon (MS Ribbon) header to a string resource works while doing that using the binding property doesn't work.